# Is this partial dependency?

Tags: relational-theory

I have this relation:

```
R = ABCDE
F: AB->DE, AC->B, DE->C, AE->C, C->AB.
```

Is **AC->B** a partial dependency in F?

I'm guessing it is, because

C->AB can be decomposed to

```
C->A
C->B
```

from where we can conclude that there exists a subset of AC (C in our case) which goes into B, that is

**C->B.**

I couldn't find a formal definition on the internet, so I would like it if someone could confirm my assumption.

Comment: I found a definition at [http://www.basicsofcomputer.com/functional_dependencies_and_normalization.htm]: "A dependency in which one or more non-key attributes are functionally dependent .on part (but not all) of the primary key is known as partial functional dependency."

Comment: @miracle173: Oooh, that's a bad definition. [This one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) is better, but still not perfect (describing 2NF): "a table is in 2NF if and only if it is in 1NF and no non prime attribute is dependent on any proper subset of any candidate key of the table."

Answer (score 3):

In order for AC->B to be a partial key dependency, it has to satisfy these conditions.

- AC must be a candidate key. (Not necessarily the primary key.)
- One of these functional dependencies must hold.

  - A->B, or
  - C->B

So the first question I'd ask myself is, "Is AC a candidate key of F?"